# SelectNodes returning 0 elements

Tags: xml, namespaces, xmldocument, xmlnode, selectnodes

I am losing my mind with namespaces. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to use SelectNodes after following most posts on how to do it.

My xml:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProgramFiles">
      <Component ..../>
      <Component ..../>
      <Component ..../>
```

What I've tried:

```
 xnManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
 xnManager.AddNamespace("wx", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi");

 //XmlNodeList aNodes = doc.SelectNodes("//wx:Wix/wx:Fragment/wx:ComponentGroup/Component", xnManager);

 //var aNodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("wx:Wix/Fragment/ComponentGroup/Component");

 //System.Xml.XmlNodeList aNodes = doc.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()=\"Component\"]");
```

What am I missing? All results return 0 elements. The document is valid and loaded into doc.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following conceptual example.

It is using **LINQ to XML** API.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>
        <Fragment>
            <ComponentGroup Id='ProgramFiles'>
                <Component>One</Component>
                <Component>Two</Component>
                <Component>Three</Component>
            </ComponentGroup>
        </Fragment>
    </Wix>");

    XNamespace ns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
    foreach (XElement xelem in xdoc.Descendants(ns + "Component"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(xelem.Value);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
One
Two
Three
```

Comment: Nice, neat code that works (+1).  Might want to add why OP's XPath attempts failed: First two neglect to account for *all* descendent elements being in default namespace; third XPath looks ok -- issue may be in support code or elsewhere.